# grafana: use a variable in the definition of another variable

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I'm trying to construct a dashboard for git projects.  I have an influxDB, which has data for each build in a repo, for every branch.

I have a variable already defined for repository, with the query `show tag values with key=repo`.  What I want is, once that value is set, to have a second variable called `branch`, that uses the `repo` variable in it's query.  I've tried `show tag values with key=branch where repo='$repo'`, but that doesn't work.

I'm not sure how to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to surround the variable in slashes:

```
show tag values with key=branch where repo=/$repo/
```

Answer (score 0):

Also using InfluxDB. `/$variable/` didn't work for me, I needed slightly different escaping. For this particular query I needed `=~` instead of `=` as well.

```
select "end" from "summary" where "build" =~ /^$build$/
```